# How to get the direction for certain coordinates in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I have my current location. (using location manager)
I have coordinates(longitude and latitude) of the destination.

I need to use those to get the direction in degrees from my location to the destination.

Comment: You can use google API for getting direction from one location to another location. If you are in US/Europe countries then use Apple's direction API           https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirectionsRequest_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011745

Comment: Please tell us what you already tried and what is not working. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can almost type that straight in. It is just some mathematical formulas. At least make an attempt instead of just asking someone to give you the code

Comment: I made attempts before asking! And if you don't know how it is done don't just throw comments! @Pualw11